# HAML - add type=text/css to <style> tag with :css filter

Tags: css, haml, sass, noscript

I'm trying to add some inline CSS in a HAML file. I thought that

```
%noscript
  :css
    .pagecontent {display:none;}
```

would produce:

```
<noscript>
  <style type="text/css">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
      .pagecontent {display:none;}
    /*]]>*/
  </style>
</noscript>
```

but it doesn't. As it leaves out the `type="text/css"` and produces:

```
<noscript>
  <style>
    /*<![CDATA[*/
      .pagecontent {display:none;}
    /*]]>*/
  </style>
</noscript>
```

I could just use brute force `%style(type="text/css")` but HAML's `:css` filter seems like it *should* be more "elegant"?!? Or, did I miss something (I rarely deal with inline CSS) and `type` is no longer necessary?!?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Haml will output the `type` attribute if the `format` option is set to `xhtml` or `html4`. If the format is set to `html5` the attribute will be omitted.

See the [Haml docs on options](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options) and the [source of the CSS filter](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/3.1.4/lib/haml/filters.rb#L223).

The default in Haml  3.1.x is `xhtml`, except in Rails when it is `html5` since that is the Rails default. In Haml 4+ the default will be `html5` throughout. (Also in 4+ the CDATA tags will be left out by default when the format is `html4` or `html5`.)

Comment: Correct link to Haml options is [https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#options](https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#options)

Answer (score 10):

[`type` defaults to `text/css` as of HTML5](http://developers.whatwg.org/semantics.html#attr-style-type), and has always done so in practice (i.e. in browser implementations).

So yes, `type="text/css"` is not necessary (and never has been).